# Perform action when object is visible in viewport

Tags: javascript

I have a div on my page, and I would like the background color to change when the viewer scrolls down to it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have used CSS3 with something like this...

```
var elemTop = $('div').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(this).scrollTop() == elemTop) {
       $('div').removeClass('hidden');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The commenter above is right. You should try something first and when you get stuck, the community will help you get unstuck. That said, here's a quick jquery to solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offsetTop = $('#test').offset().top, //offset from top of element - element has id of 'test'
        finalOffset = offsetTop - document.documentElement.clientHeight; //screen size
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var whereAmI = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(whereAmI >= offsetTop){
            console.log("i've arrived at the destination");
        }
    })
})
```

Note that the above code executes the `console.log()` at every point past your requirement (meaning from there downwards). In case you want the execution to happen only one, you need to adapt the code a bit. One more note - if you're checking this in a fiddle, this `document.documentElement.clientHeight` needs to be adapted to work in an iframe. So test it on your local machine.

Comment: Sorry, searched a couple times and never found that question ;)